# Make discord bot connect to vc with deafen

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use `voice = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()` to connect my bot to voice channel and i want the bot connect and deafen himself

All my code:

```
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    arg = message.content.split(' ')
    if message.content.startswith('>play'):
        voice = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(YouTube(arg[1]).streams.first().download()))
        await message.guild.change_voice_state(channel=voice, self_mute=True, self_deaf=False)
client.run('my token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `await message.guild.change_voice_state(channel=voice, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)`

Copy-paste this code that I wrote after looking at your comments:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
        return await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!')

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        vc = ctx.voice_client
    
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(YouTube(arg[1]).streams.first().download()))
    await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=vc, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)

bot.run('my token')
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\edgar\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 26, in on_message
    await message.guild.change_voice_state(channel=voice, self_mute=True, self_deaf=False)
  File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 2194, in change_voice_state
    channel_id = channel.id if channel else None
AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @megagaming edit your question and put in the rest of your code

Comment: i edit my question to deafen but its just set self_deaf=True but i have error

Comment: @megagaming ok, i've edited my post. Look at the code, and replace it with yours.

Comment: You're using a `VoiceClient` object instead of the `VoiceChannel` object when you have `await ctx.guild.change_voice_state(channel=vc, self_mute=False, self_deaf=True)`, hence the error

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'id'